# How to search for a pattern like [num:0] and replace it?

Tags: php, string

I know there are lots of tutorials and question on replacing something in a string.

But I can't find a single one on what I want to do!

Lets say I have a string like this

```
$string="Hi! [num:0]";
```

And an example array like this

```
$array=array();
$array[0]=array('name'=>"na");
$array[1]=array('name'=>"nam");
```

Now what I want is that PHP should first search for the pattern like `[num:x]` where `x` is a valid key from the array.
And then replace it with the matching key of the array. For example, the string given above should become: `Hi! na`

I was thinking of doing this way:

1. Search for the pattern.
2. If found, call a function which checks if the number is valid or not.
3. If valid, returns the name from the array of that key like 0 or 1 etc.
4. PHP replaces the value returned from the function in the string in place of the pattern.

But I can't find a way to execute the idea. How do I match that pattern and call the function for every match?

This is just the way that I am thinking to do. Any other method will also work.

If you have any doubts about my question, please ask in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$string="Hi! [num:0]";
$array=array();
$array[0]=array('name'=>"na");
$array[1]=array('name'=>"nam");


echo preg_replace('#(\!)?\s+\[num:(\d+)\]#ie','isset($array[\2]) ? "\1 ".$array[\2]["name"] : " "',$string);
```

Comment: Works perfect for valid keys. But when a key is not valid i want to remove the patter that is replace it by a blank. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean,so when `$string = "Hi! [num:3]"`,what should the results be?

Comment: The result should be just "Hi "

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a curious if i want to do some thing more than this can i also use any function in place of isset and the returned value would be replaced right ? :P

Comment: Ye,you can wrote any php codes there when you put 'e' modifier after pattern,you can also check the `preg_replace_callback` function which would be a better one if you have much codes to do with your replacement.:-)

Comment: I have another problem on this. If i try to do this on this string : "Hi! [num:0] with [num:1]" it would just replace the first match and not the second one. Please help me with this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the overhead of Regex, and your string format remains same; you could use:

```
<?php

$string="Hi! [num:0]"; 
echo_name($string);          // Hi John
echo "<br />";
$string="Hello! [num:10]"; 
echo_name($string);          // No names, only Hello

// Will echo Hi + Name
function echo_name($string){
$array=array();
$array[0]=array('name'=>"John");
$array[1]=array('name'=>"Doe");

$string = explode(" ", $string);
$string[1] = str_replace("[num:", "", $string[1]);
$string[1] = str_replace("]", "", $string[1]);

if(array_key_exists($string[1], $array)){
    echo $string[0]." ".$array[$string[1]]["name"];
} else {
    echo $string[0]." ";
}
}// function echo_sal ENDs

?>
```

[Live: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qy2uwW](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qy2uwW)

Assumptions:

- $string always will have only one space, exactly before `[num:X]`.
- `[num:X]` is always in the same format.

Of course you could skip the str_replace lines if you could make your input to simple
`Hi! 0` *or* `Hello! 10`